# Different constructor called when using braces and parens

Tags: c++, initialization

I was writing a function to process command line arguments.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

void process(std::vector<std::string> args)
{
    std::copy(args.begin(), args.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>{std::cout, "\n"});   //show the arguments
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //process((&argv[0], &argv[argc]));   //ERROR
    process({&argv[0], &argv[argc]});
}
```

My question is **why the parentheses version does not work.**
I want to construct the vector with the iterator version. I understand that the `std::initializer_list` will have a high priority to be selected, but this seems not to be the case, because multiple arguments can be successfully processed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
process((&argv[0], &argv[argc]));
```

you're using [the comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) to really do

```
process(&argv[argc]);
```

This is of course wrong as you don't have a `process` function overload that takes a pointer to a pointer to `char` (i.e. `char**`).

The brace-enclosed list is recognized by the compiler as a possible variant of the [`std::vector` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) (number 5 in the list in the linked reference).

Comment: It's such a stupid mistake I made. Another good reason to use braces I guess. The title is misleading in this case since it's not the reason of constructors.

Comment: @szppeter • can you remove the set of the semantic-changing from what was desired parens?  `process(&argv[0], &argv[argc]);`

Comment: @Eljay No, this will try to convert from ``char**`` to ``std::vector<std::string>>``

Comment: @szppeter • Ah yes, need to declare the vector, `process(std::vector<std::string>(argv + 1, argv + argc));`